# Can I use gerund of the verb "to have"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is this correct?  "I am looking forward to having a conversation with you?" I am asking about the word "having"...  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct. "Looking forward to" is always followed by a gerund, not by an infinitive (that is, when it is to be followed by a verb).

This is from the Cambridge Dictionary:

"Look forward to something means to be pleased or excited that it is going to happen. The 'to' in look forward to is a preposition, so we must follow it by a noun phrase or a verb in the -ing form: I'm looking forward to the holidays.
We’re looking forward to going to Switzerland next month."

Comment: I beg leave to doubt the rule that "looking forward to" is always followed by a gerund. Many times I have myself been looking forward to lunch, and lunch is no gerund. I expect that my students have often been looking forward to me ending the lesson, which differs from my ending the lesson in that "ending" is now a present participle, now a gerund.

Comment: "Look forward to something means to be pleased or excited that it is going to happen. The 'to' in look forward to is a preposition, so we must follow it by a noun phrase or a verb in the -ing form: I'm looking forward to the holidays." This is from the Cambridge dictionary.

Comment: @Shef Please [edit] your post to include the reference, as comments are ephemeral. If you are new to Stack Exchange, I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of our standards and operations.